# How to refine the DataContext locally for a Grid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I can't find the way to move the reference to property `P1` at `Grid` level.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding P1.Name}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding P1.Age}"/>
</Grid>
```

`P1` is a property of the View-Model instance set as `DataContext` for the Window. It references a `Person` instance with `Name` and `Age` properties. Is there a possibility to "refine" this `DataContext` for the `Grid`, so that cells can be bound like:

```
<Grid DataContext="P1">
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
</Grid>
```

I'm trying to do this so that different Grid can be bound to different Person (P1, P2, ...).

Comment: `DataContext="{Binding P1}"`

Comment: @ASh: Indeed :-)

Answer (score 0):

As kindly suggested by @ASh, the correct syntax is to use a `Binding` object to set the DataContext. If two Person instances P1 and P2 where to be shown side-by-side, this code would work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!-- Binding first grid DataContext to P1 -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding P1}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
    </Grid>

    <!-- Binding second grid DataContext to P2 -->
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding P2}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Age}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```